# ld: library not found for -lintl on mac os x lion

Tags: git, installation

I installed git 1.7.4.4 long time ago.
And I want to upgrade to git 1.7.11.

However, when I run

> sudo make prefix=/usr/local install

it gives this error:

> ld: library not found for -lintl
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: *** [git-credential-store] Error 1

How to solve it?

thanks

Answer (score 22):

I just had the same error message while trying to build wireshark on OSX Lion. It looks like GNU gettext provides libintl. In my case, I had installed gettext via homebrew, but the symlinks were not in place, so running:

```
brew link gettext
```

fixed the problem for me.

If you don't have `gettext` installed, you may want to install it, either using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I certainly haven't tried it, but [this](http://code.google.com/p/rudix/downloads/detail?name=static-libintl-0.18.1.1-5.pkg&can=2&q=label%3aRudix-2012) appears to be a libintl someone built for OS X.

If you don't know how to point configure to it, you can just copy it into your /usr/lib folder so it can be found.