# Unable to install R packages due to library not found

Tags: r, installation, package

In any R package I try to install, I get the following error message:

```
ld: library not found for -lintl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [utf8.so] Error 1
```

I'm not sure how to make this a reprex, but I am running:
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

What does this error message (`ld: library not found for -lintl`) mean and how can I fix it to be able to install R packages (the packages I have tried are texreg and lme4)? Thank you.

Edit: I apologize, I thought I had included this with my post. I am not missing `gettext` (as per [Link error installing Rcpp "library not found for -lintl"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370363/link-error-installing-rcpp-library-not-found-for-lintl)), and I followed the instructions to export the `LPDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` so that they are linked.

As best I can tell, the problem is the ~/.R/Makevars file, which currently looks like this, where I've commented out things I've added to it based on googling.

```
CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/bin/gcc-9
CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/bin/g++-9
CXX11=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/bin/g++-9
CXX14=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/bin/g++-9
cxx17=/usr/local/cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/bin/g++-9
cxx1X=/usr/local/cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/bin/g++-9
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/lib
#FLIBS=-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0

#CC=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
#CXX=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
#CXX1X=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
#CXX98=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
#CXX11=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
#CXX14=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
#CXX17=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
#LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/clang4/lib
```

Comment: I googled [`"library not found for -lintl"`](https://www.google.com/search?q="library+not+found+for+-lintl") (the quotes are important) and found several references to a missing `gettext`, such as here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21370363 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11151197.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to remove all the lines from `~/.R/Makevars` and I was able to install `lme4`. I did get some warnings, but `library(lme4)` works.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a mac with an Apple Silicon chip (like the M1), then you can try adding this to `~/.R/Makevars`:

```
CFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include
CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include
CXXFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include
CXX11FLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include
LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/lib
```

This allows R to find the needed libraries. You will need to first ensure you have the needed compilers and dependencies installed. You can usually do this with `brew`.